# How to do javascript promise chaining in more elegant way?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I work on my Angular2/firebase side project and stop for a while on this chunk of code. What I am trying to do here is to create a new account with signupUser method and then, only when it succeeded, call another method saveNewUserInDatabase. If I do it like underneath, method router.navigate does not wait 5 seconds.

```
    //EXAMPLE 1

    public onSignup(): void {
    this.authService.signupUser(this.signupForm.value)
        .then(response => {
            let userObject = {
                uid: response.auth.uid,
                email: response.auth.email
            };

            setTimeout(() => this.authService.saveNewUserInDatabase(userObject) , 5000)})
        .then(() => {
                setTimeout(() => { this.router.navigate(['/map'])}, 1500);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

However if I nest .then method like in the example below, it works as I wish to work.

```
//EXAMPLE 2

public onSignup(): void {
    this.authService.signupUser(this.signupForm.value)
        .then(response => {
            let userObject = {
                uid: response.auth.uid,
                email: response.auth.email
            };

            setTimeout(() => this.authService.saveNewUserInDatabase(userObject)
                .then(() => {
                        setTimeout(() => { this.router.navigate(['/map'])}, 1500);
                    }
                ), 5000)
        })
        .catch(error => { 
             console.log(error)
        });
}
```

service methods

```
public signupUser(user: UserLogin): firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    return this.af.auth.createUser({email : user.email, password: user.password});
}

public saveNewUserInDatabase(user): firebase.database.ThenableReference {
    return firebase.database().ref().child("users").push(user);
}
```

The second solution works (the user is navigated after 5 seconds to the /map path). Nonetheless I do not think that nesting promise in promise is a good practice. How can I chain promises here like

```
.then()
.then()
```

and make second .then triggered after first is completed?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you expect your chain to wait for those `setTimeout`s? Then you need to use promises.

Comment: does saveNewUserInDatabase return a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do as you want you need to return a promise in the first then:

```
public onSignup(): void {
    this.authService.signupUser(this.signupForm.value)
        .then(response => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
             let userObject = {
                 uid: response.auth.uid,
                 email: response.auth.email
              };
              setTimeout(() => resolve(this.authService.saveNewUserInDatabase(userObject)), 5000)  
        })
        .then( () => {
            setTimeout(() => { this.router.navigate(['/map'])}, 1500)
        })
        .catch(error => { 
         console.log(error)
        });
   }
```

Comment: I have read something on promises and play around with your solution. The only thing what is actually missing here is `return` keyword before `new Promise`. That is actually what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a delay function that you can pipe into your promise chain.

```js
//EXAMPLE 2

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}

function onSignup() {
  this.authService.signupUser(this.signupForm.value)
  .then(response => {
     const userObject = {
       uid: response.auth.uid,
       email: response.auth.email
     }
     return userObject
   })
   .then(this.authService.saveNewUserInDatabase)
   .then(delay(5000))
   .then(() => {
     this.router.navigate(['/map'])
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
   });
}
```

Comment: You still have to pass a callback to `then`, though

Comment: Probably I did not make myself clear in the description as setTimeout method was just my helper function on debug purpose. I do not really need any delay. Solution from Gabriel works for me well. Thank you for your time though!